# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path' What is the solution?

Tags: python, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

When I run the code I wrote in cmd, I encounter this error.
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe")
TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Could it be because I specified the wrong directory path to geckodriver?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to run selenium driver from your local path.
If you are using Selenium 4 or later, you should use the Service class to set the executable path, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

gecko_path = "C:/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe"
service = Service(gecko_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

If you are using Selenium 3, you can specify the executable_path directly when creating the Firefox webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver

gecko_path = "C:/geckodriver/geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gecko_path)
```

If you don't want to use local path you can try this

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```